# Is there a way to prevent url decoding on firebase hosting?

Tags: reverse-proxy, google-cloud-run, firebase-hosting, urlencode

I'm using Firebase hosting to connect my domain with a cloud-run service.
The configuration is really simple:

```
  {
    "hosting": {
      "rewrites": [{
        "source": "**",
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "my-cloudrun-service",
          "region": "europe-central2"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

My application has a couple of endpoints where you can provide a name containing special characters. The issue is that the request to the cloud-run service proxied by Firebase hosting contains decoded characters.
For example request to
https://my-domain.example/bands/ac%2Fdc
Is received by my application as `/bands/ac/dc`.

I want to configure the Firebase hosting that way it will not decode url at all. I know that Nginx reverse proxy has that possibility, is it possible with Firebase? I could not find anything related to url encoding in the documentation